# I keep getting a type/namespace error when I try to define my two motion controllers. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, motion-control, htc-vive

I'm trying to get motion controls working (particularly making it act like a joystick) but I keep getting this error "The type or namespace name 'SteamVR_Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Particularly on these two lines...

```
private SteamVR_Controller.Device rightDevice;
private SteamVR_Controller.Device leftDevice;
```

I made sure to add using Valve.VR; at the top of my script/class. The weird thing is I've had no issue using the code above before in other scripts but now in this script in particular it doesn't want to work. What am I doing wrong here?

The script in full:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Valve.VR;


/// MouseLook rotates the transform based on the mouse delta.
/// Minimum and Maximum values can be used to constrain the possible rotation

/// To make an FPS style character:
/// - Create a capsule.
/// - Add the MouseLook script to the capsule.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookX. (You want to only turn character but not tilt it)
/// - Add FPSInputController script to the capsule
///   -> A CharacterMotor and a CharacterController component will be automatically added.

/// - Create a camera. Make the camera a child of the capsule. Reset it's transform.
/// - Add a MouseLook script to the camera.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookY. (You want the camera to tilt up and down like a head. The character already turns.)
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

    private SteamVR_Controller.Device rightDevice;
    private SteamVR_Controller.Device leftDevice;

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
        }
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
}
```

Also as per request here is a script where the code was working perfectly fine...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Valve.VR;

// Require a character controller to be attached to the same game object
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterMotor))]
[AddComponentMenu("Character/FPS Input Controller")]

public class FPSInputController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SteamVR_Controller.Device rightDevice;
    private SteamVR_Controller.Device leftDevice;

    private CharacterMotor motor;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<CharacterMotor>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rightDevice = SteamVR_Controller.Input(SteamVR_Controller.GetDeviceIndex(SteamVR_Controller.DeviceRelation.Rightmost));
        leftDevice = SteamVR_Controller.Input(SteamVR_Controller.GetDeviceIndex(SteamVR_Controller.DeviceRelation.Leftmost));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Get the input vector from kayboard or analog stick
        //Vector3 directionVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        Vector2 tpp = rightDevice.GetAxis();
        Vector3 directionVector = new Vector3(tpp.x, 0, tpp.y);

        if (directionVector != Vector3.zero)
        {
            // Get the length of the directon vector and then normalize it
            // Dividing by the length is cheaper than normalizing when we already have the length anyway
            float directionLength = directionVector.magnitude;
            directionVector = directionVector / directionLength;

            // Make sure the length is no bigger than 1
            directionLength = Mathf.Min(1.0f, directionLength);

            // Make the input vector more sensitive towards the extremes and less sensitive in the middle
            // This makes it easier to control slow speeds when using analog sticks
            directionLength = directionLength * directionLength;

            // Multiply the normalized direction vector by the modified length
            directionVector = directionVector * directionLength;
        }

        // Apply the direction to the CharacterMotor
        motor.inputMoveDirection = transform.rotation * directionVector;
        motor.inputJump = Input.GetButton("Jump");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code from when it worked before for comparison?

Comment: @Tashus I've update the question to include a working example.

Comment: Hmm. Those certainly seem indistinguishable up to that point. Is it possible that VR isn't enable in Player Settings? I'm not sure if that would cause the problem though.

Comment: @Tashus Everything is configured properly. The weird part is I've used literally that identical code in other scripts but this is the one giving me an issue.

Comment: Try right clicking on your project...properties...and set the `Target Framework` to `Unity 3.5 full base Class Libraries` and then rebuild it. Try with the other projects in the solution if doing it on the main work doesn't work. I had reference issues with Unity (although not with the VR library) and that solved it for me.

Comment: @keyboardP Very strange. I tried doing that and it flashes white but doesn't open the properties window.

Comment: @Sie - That's...different haha. May be worth restarting Visual Studio to see if it's just an IDE issue

Comment: @keyboardP Just did :/ but no dice.

Comment: @keyboardP Well I got it open but I don't see that option: https://i.imgur.com/G4p9lcc.png

Comment: @Sie - Fourth one from the bottom (sorry, missed out the `.net` part)

Comment: @keyboardP Well I just tried that and but now VS is back to do that thing where it flashes and doesn't open the Window. I'm so done with VS right now.

Comment: @Sie - that's quite a strange issue. Hopefully if it starts working again, you can try it. Alternatively, you could try (although I recommend a backup of the project) to manually change the `csproj` file. Right click...Unload Project then replace `TargetFrameworkVersion` and `TargetFrameworkProfile` with `    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Unity Subset v3.5</TargetFrameworkProfile>`

Comment: @Sie - May also want to try the suggestions here, seems like it's happened to a few people http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262557/visual-studio-2015-properties-window-is-blank-sometimes